# InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element did not match expected type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to execute an IN query with by using Spring Data. My model looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", schema = "public", catalog = "postgres")
public class CustomerEntity {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int balance;
    private String bankId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "balance")
    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(int balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "bank_id")
    public String getBankId() {
        return bankId;
    }

    public void setBankId(String bankId) {
        this.bankId = bankId;
    }
```

And my repository interface looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionsRepository extends JpaRepository<TransactionsEntity, Long> {

    List<TransactionsEntity> findByCustomerIdIn(List<CustomerEntity> customerEntities);
```

}

The problem is that when I try to execute this code
 `List<TransactionsEntity> transactionsEntitiesList = transactionsRepository.findByCustomerIdIn(customerEntitiesList);`

I get this exception:

`Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value element [org.example.domain.admin.CustomerEntity@6a1a2a4] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value element [org.example.domain.admin.CustomerEntity@6a1a2a4] did not match expected type [java.lang.String (n/a)]`

Update: **TransactionsEntity.class**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transactions", schema = "public", catalog = "postgres")
public class TransactionsEntity {

    private String id;
    private String amount;
    private String customerId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "amount")
    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    public String getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }

    public void setCustomerId(String customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        TransactionsEntity that = (TransactionsEntity) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(that.id) : that.id != null) return false;
        if (amount != null ? !amount.equals(that.amount) : that.amount != null) return false;
        if (customerId != null ? !customerId.equals(that.customerId) : that.customerId != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (amount != null ? amount.hashCode() : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (customerId != null ? customerId.hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your TransationEntity too?

Comment: I've updated the original post. Meanwhile I have solved the problem, I was passing an Object to the query, but it wanted a String. I guess I was giving spring-data too much credit :) I am not happy with the result, since I first get a list of customers, then I have to create a separate list of client id (String) values and query using that list. Maybe there is another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says in the exception Spring expects a `String` because your `customer_id` in your `TransactionEntity` is a String, but you are inputting a `CustomerEntity`. Instead you should input a `List<String>` with the list of your customer ids.

Btw shouldn't your `customer_id` be an `int` assuming you set it to the `id` of your `CustomerEntity`?

Then you could do something like

```
List<Integer> customerIds = customerEntitiesList.stream().map(CustomerEntity::getId).collect(Collectors.toList());
```